# Linux shell script - search for a string (date) in the first line of a file and copy it to a new file?

Tags: linux, string, shell

How can I search a string in the first line of a file (and the string happens to be a date) and copy it to a new file?

I have the first line of my file:

```
START,11/12/2012 19:30,,Start 'suite_ABN_R71',Test 'suite_ABN_R71' started,
```

The string I want is "`11/12/2012`".

The date in the file is different for different file. So I can't just search for 11/12/2012 if that makes sense.

Comment: Copy the date or the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files always start with `START,` I would do

```
head -1 filename | cut -c7-16 > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
head -n1 -q <list of files> | grep '11/12/2012' > <new filename>
```

You can pipe it through `sed` if necessary.

Comment: Hi Ed, the date I search for isn't always the same. Sorry I didn't make it clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regular expression to match a date in your format, you can use:

```
grep -oP '(?<=,)(0\d|1[012])/([012]\d|3[01])/\d{4}(?= )'
```